# spring-data-mongodb dose not map integer values properly

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

spring-data-mongodb 1.7.2.RELEASE auto save integer as double is mongodb.
Document to object mapping is ok.
But when I read documents as java.util.Map, all integer values turned into double values :(
Is it possible to make spring-data-mongodb save integer as Integer(X) not a double in mongodb.
Is it a bug?

something like this:

```
@Document
public class Foo {
    private Integer count;
    ...
}

fooRepository.save(fooInstance);
```

in mongodb document, field 'count' saved as double not NumberInt(X)

Comment: Please share some code/configuration to help us better understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a class representation, you can specify how it is going to be used. So, in this case if you use jackson mapping from the document in mongo db and in your class you use values like int value; it will be mapped as that.

Comment: I read document in another project and do some simple batch process, there is no original classes in context. So I must make spring-data-mongodb save integer as NumberInt(X) in db...

Comment: Yes, declaring the field as int (primitive) is storing as Int32 in mongodb.